# Wordpress query posts by title issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using below code to get posts by title.

```
protected function get_post_by_title($post_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'post' ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", $post_title, $post_type ));

    if ( $post )
        return get_page($post, $output);

    return null;

}
```

Everything is working fine, except it will not find the posts having single quote in title. Consider below as $post_title.

```
This is a test's post
```

$wpdb->prepare will return query something like below.

```
This is a test\\\'s post
```

Which will return no result. Can anyone please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should get the slug instead of the real title, and then check if the slug is the same as xxx slug

Comment: actually am using XML-RPC calls to remotely add posts to wordpress and slug is being calculated by wordpress itself, all i have is the post title.

Comment: but you can create a slug, from the given wordpress title -> sanitize_title() and then compare that!

Comment: Thanks @Xatenev it worked like a charm. Thanks for your quick help as well as hangout offer :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never compare with the real title. Wordpress offers you the possibility to create slugs without all those weird characters like " " or "'". Then you can compare them:

Use `sanitize_title()` to create a slug from your title, and then you can compare them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should fix the issue,

DOC: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

```
protected function get_post_by_title($post_title, $output = OBJECT, $post_type = 'post' ) 
{
    global $wpdb;
    $post_title = mysqli_real_escape_string($post_title);  //escape special meaning
    $post = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_title = %s AND post_type= %s", $post_title, $post_type ));

    if ( $post )
        return get_page($post, $output);

    return null;

}
```

edit:

That might not work, try this,

```
$post_title = addslashes($post_title);
```

Let me know which one works for you.

Comment: Have tried this earlier, but title got empty after calling function "mysqli_real_escape_string"

Comment: Yeah, that's what i thought, did you try `addslashes()` instead?